# getting phone number from android device

Tags: android, android-intent

Yes I am using the correct permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

And here is my code:

```
private String getDevicePhoneNumber() {
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
        getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}
```

The phone is returning lambda to me: the empty string.

Does anyone know how to get this right? I need this to work for android Froyo (`2.2` ) and up

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong, it's just that this method may not always return a phone number. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number()

Comment: Do you know the correct method?

Comment: You are using the correct method. It doesn't always return a phone number.

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem indeed. There is no one solution to that will always work.
It is not stored on all SIM cards nor is it accessible always from the carrier network.

Physical address verification might be even require in some countries.

The assignment of a phone number assignment happens on the network - and can be changed without changing the SIM card or device (e.g. this is how porting is supported to work when moving from one carrier to another..).

you best bet is to ask the user, as strange as that might sound..